# How do I share the home folder or the opt folder using NFS?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have seen tutorials of sharing a brand new folder but what if I want to share an already existing folder, for example `opt` or `home`. For a brand new folder is intuitive, I just create such folder, e.g., `mdkir /shared_folder`, then I install nfs in the server and the client, and last I add one line to `/etc/exports` and mount it.

My problem comes with the `home` folder. I have 2 machines and both have the same user, so, does it mean that if I use NFS, the client home folder dies? I cannot find a proper tutorial for such a case, so far what I found is that I should create again a folder, e.g., `/shared_folder/home`, and then use this folder for sharing. Does it mean that I require a symbolic link? Can you explain me this please? It is my first installation.
Moreover, if I'm planning to add more users, then I also read that it is better to share only the users folders, so does it mean now that I have to create instead `/shared_folder/home/user1`? And everytime I create a new user I need to keep adding a new subfolder like `/shared_folder/home/user2` ? Is my analysis correct?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting a folder from an NFS server and mounting it on a client machine are two related but separate things.

- On the NFS server, you tell it which folders to export (and other details such as which clients are allowed to mount them, whether they're read-only or read-write, etc).
- On the NFS client, you tell it which exports to mount from the server and also **where** to mount them.

  The **where** is important.

  It is basically the same as mounting a partition from a local disk at a particular location ("mount point") in the local directory tree (e.g. /dev/sda1 might be your / filesystem, while /dev/sda2 is mounted as /home).

  You can mount a local disk partition or a directory exported by a server (or any other kind of fileystem) wherever you like on your local system.

BTW, The reason for running `mdkir /shared_folder` is to create a mount-point in the local fileystem for the NFS share to be mounted on - same as there would need to be a /home sub-directory in / for /dev/sda2 to be mounted on, if /home was a separate partition.  Neither can be mounted on a directory that doesn't exist.   A mount-point is just a directory that you're using as a location to mount a filesystem.

Personally, I wouldn't use `/shared_folder` as a mount-point - it's inconveniently long and has an underscore in it so requires using the shift key.  I'd use something shorter and less annoying to type, like `/shared` or `/nfs`.

On my home network, I have several machines that export various directories to the local network, so I mount them on the client machines under /nfs/hostname.   e.g. my main file server is called "ganesh", so I mount exports from ganesh on my workstation under `/nfs/ganesh/`, and my mythtv box is called "indra" so I mount the TV recordings from indra under `/nfs/indra/`.  I also use various symlinks as convenient short-cuts to particular directories under /nfs/ganesh and /nfs/indra.

> My problem comes with the home folder. I have 2 machines and both have
> the same user, so, does it mean that if I use NFS, the client home
> folder dies?

Not unless you mount it over the user's home directory on the client - which is something you *can* do if you choose but is not something that you *must* do.   It's something you'd do if you didn't want the user to have a local home directory on the client machine, if you wanted all of their files to be on the server.

If you're mounting, say, `server:/home` as `/shared/home` on the client then both `/home/username` AND `/shared/home/username` will be available on the client.

BTW, if you have the same users on two or more different machines, it's best if they have the same UIDs on all machines (e.g. if user `user1` has uid 1000 on the server, it's best if `user1` is uid 1000 on the client).  NFS does have uid & gid mapping capabilities but in my experience, it's best to avoid user and group ownership problems by having relevant users and groups have the same UIDs and GIDs on both machines.   In large environments (e.g. corporate or academic) this is often achieved using nis or LDAP or Active Directory or some other network service for account details.  In home or small business environments, setting this is probably overkill and it's easier to just be careful about uids and gids when creating accounts and groups.

> Does it mean that I require a symbolic link?

Not unless you want one.  A symlink can be a useful convenience so you don't have to type the full path every time, but it isn't required.

e.g. user `user1` might have a symlink called "nfs" or "server" or whatever pointing to `/shared/home/user1` in their home dir, but that's optional. They can just specify the full /shared/home/user1/... path when required.

> if I'm planning to add more users, then I also read that it is better
> to share only the users folders, so does it mean now that I have to
> create instead /shared_folder/home/user1

Some people do that, but it's really only useful if you've got lots of users (hundreds or more) and you want to run an auto-mounter so that user directories are only mounted when the user logs in (and unmounted when they log out) or when that users files are accessed (e.g. by a cron job).

For a home or small business network, this is far more trouble than it's worth.  Just export /home on the server and mount it on the client - all sub-directories will be available.